# how to plot a graph with the oryginal order of y-axis values?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some matrix with n rows and 2 columns. I want to plot the values from the second column as a function of those from the first one. The problem is that the values from the first column begins with some greater values which decrease, e.g. 
5
4
3
2
1
Therefore, when I plot the function the graph is automatically flipped i the way that 1 is on the left. How to avoid this flipping? 
I know that I could invert the graph, but I'd like to have an universal solution, which works also for datasets where the column starts with smaller numbers.

Answer (score 2):

After plotting the data of your matrix `M`, add the following condition:

```
if(~issorted(M(:, 1)))
    set(gca, 'Xdir', 'reverse');
end
```

The function [`issorted`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/issorted.html) will check if the first column is sorted in ascending order, and if it's not, then the x-axis of your plot will be reversed.